# Group array rows by multiple column values and sum another column within each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I'm trying to group the data in an array of associative arrays by three columns (`year`, `month`, `grupo`) and sum another column (`quantity`).

Given an array like:

```
$in = [
    ['year' => '2010', 'month' => '11', 'grupo' => '2', 'quantity' => 3],
    ['year' => '2010', 'month' => '11', 'grupo' => '3', 'quantity' => 4],
    ['year' => '2011', 'month' => '2', 'grupo' => '2', 'quantity' => 4],
    ['year' => '2011', 'month' => '2', 'grupo' => '2', 'quantity' => 4],
    ['year' => '2012', 'month' => '3', 'grupo' => '4', 'quantity' => 3]
    ['year' => '2012', 'month' => '3', 'grupo' => '4', 'quantity' => 3]
];
```

I want get:

```
[
    ['year' => '2010', 'month' => '11', 'grupo' => '2', 'quantity' => 3],
    ['year' => '2010', 'month' => '11', 'grupo' => '3', 'quantity' => 4],
    ['year' => '2011', 'month' => '2', 'grupo' => '2', 'quantity' => 8],
    ['year' => '2012', 'month' => '3', 'grupo' => '4', 'quantity' => 6]
]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($in as $row) {
    if (!isset($out[$row['year']['month']['grupo']])) {
        $out[$row['year']['month']['grupo']] = array(
            'year' => $row['year'],
            'month' => $row['month'],
            'grupo' => $row['grupo'],
            'quantity' => 0,
        );
    }
    $out[$row['year']['month']['grupo']]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
}
$out = array_values($out);
```

but it fails while trying to group the 3 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the earlier answers overlooked the desired result -- the solutions from @hellcode and @Rasclatt create unnecessarily deep structures.

The coding attempt in the question was very close to being right, there was only a flaw in generating unique grouping keys in the first level.

To generate unique grouping keys, you must forge a string from the multiple identifying values in the row.  In other words, "compose" a unique value from the three targeted column values -- a composite key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/A4OOV))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($in as $row) {
    $compositeKey = implode(array_slice($row, 0, 3));
    if (!isset($result[$compositeKey])) {
        $result[$compositeKey] = $row;
    } else {
        $result[$compositeKey]['quantity'] += $row['quantity'];
    }
}
var_export(
    array_values($result)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($in as $row) {
    if(! isset($out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']])) {
        $out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']]=0;
    }
    $out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']] += $row['quantity'];
}
print_r($out);
```

It will output your desired values, but as a multidimensional value array, not as a flat array with key => value pairs:

```
Array
(
    [2010] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                )

        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 8
                )

        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [4] => 6
                )

        )

)
```

But you can rearrange your array:

```
$out2 = array();
foreach($out as $year => $year_array) {
  foreach($year_array as $month => $month_array) {
    foreach($month_array as $grupo => $quantity) {
      $out2[] = array('year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'grupo' => $grupo, 'quantity' => $quantity);
    }
  }
}
print_r($out2);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2010
            [month] => 11
            [grupo] => 2
            [quantity] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2010
            [month] => 11
            [grupo] => 3
            [quantity] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2011
            [month] => 2
            [grupo] => 2
            [quantity] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [year] => 2012
            [month] => 3
            [grupo] => 4
            [quantity] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I need sort by quantity, and I was thinking in use: 

    foreach ($out as $key => $row) {
        $aux[$key] = $row['quantity'];
    }

    array_multisort($aux, SORT_DESC, $out);

Comment: I thought you would solve that alone, but here it is.

Answer (score 0):

This will retain values and also give sum.

```
foreach($in as $row) {
            $out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']]['quantity'][]  =   $row['quantity'];
            $out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']]['sum']         =   array_sum($out[$row['year']][$row['month']][$row['grupo']]['quantity']);
        }

print_r($out);
```

**GIVES**

```
Array
(
    [2010] => Array
        (
            [11] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                )

                            [sum] => 3
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 4
                                )

                            [sum] => 4
                        )

                )

        )

    [2011] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 4
                                    [1] => 4
                                )

                            [sum] => 8
                        )

                )

        )

    [2012] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [quantity] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 3
                                    [1] => 3
                                )

                            [sum] => 6
                        )

                )

        )

)
```